# Add files to local repository in GitKraken

Tags: github, gitkraken

Am new to GiKraken.

I have created a local repo and remote (origin) repo.
I have added some files to the local repo (folder on my computer).

But, Gitkraken cannot find them automatically and then cannot commit.

How to add them in GiKraken manually ?
(could not find the way to do it, even "Stage" is not shown inthe community version).

Answer (score 2):

[image: GitKraken Screenshot]

A click on **1** shows your unstaged changes in area **2**. The green symbol below **2** indicates a file that was added and is not yet added to your git repository. If you click on it, it will move to the `Staged files` area and be ready to be commited.

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, please [mark it as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. You can not create files in GitKraken, it just manages your existing files in your repository.

If you create or copy files in your repositorys' folder (via file manager or editor or by whatever means), GitKraken will know and show the files as new files in th "Unstaged Files" section, allowing to add and commit them to your repository.

Comment: Files are created on local computer, but GitKraken cannot recognize them.... How to see the "Unstaged Files" ?

Comment: You have to select the very top entry of your tree visualization (the big one in the middle). Then, the panel on the right will list `Unstaged Changes`, new files as well as modified ones.

Comment: cannot see it, do you have a screenshot to see clearly ?