# How can I add existing files to a Gitkraken repository?

Tags: git, gitkraken

This is the same question but still unresolved: [Add files to local repository in GitKraken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666360/add-files-to-local-repository-in-gitkraken)

I am new to gitkraken. I had initialized a repository with just a readme file. But now I have to also include the python files in the same folder into the repository. I am unable to figure out how to do this on git kraken. I understand I can create new file within gitkraken but not sure how to add existing files into the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, GitKraken will just reflect your repository, so nothing prevents you to use regular git commands, as [documented by GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/gitkraken-git-basics-cheat-sheet.pdf)

Second, you can make a [commit in GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/commit), which involves first staging the existing files:

[image: stage]

The `Unstaged Files` section of the GitKraken GUI should reflect the files you have created / added in your repository folder. (`myproject`, not `myproject/.git`: do not add anything in the `.git` subfolder))